# Debugging IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactor-netty

I have a question to ask.  Is there a good tips/simple way to debug exceptions with `IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1`. I tried many ways to but fails to find a good solution on debugging this. I would like to know whether there's some configuration changes (other than enabling `DEBUG` on logging, which doesn't have much helpful info) or some code changes I can update to enable more debugging information for such Netty exception.

Java code

```java
    WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder = WebClient.builder();

    if (ENDPOINTS_REQUIRE_PROXY.contains(endpoint)) {
      ReactorClientHttpConnector proxyConnector =
          new ReactorClientHttpConnector(proxyHTTPClient);
      webClientBuilder.clientConnector(proxyConnector);
    }

    return requestBodySpec
          .header("Content-Type", HEADER_VALUE_CONTENT_TYPE)
          .body(Mono.just(requestBody), requestBodyClass)
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(String.class)
          .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(alloyConfig.getTimeoutInMilliseconds()))
          .block();
```

### Environments

- Reactor version(s) used:

  - `org.projectreactor:reactor-spring:1.0.1.RELEASE`
  - `org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE`
  - `io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE`
- JVM version (`java -version`):

```
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

- OS and version (eg. `uname -a`):
  `Darwin 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Thu Oct 29 22:56:45 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.2.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

```
2020-12-11 00:29:12.498 ERROR 11918 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xebbe5eff, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:55189] Error was received while reading the incoming data. The connection will be closed.

io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
        at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.toLiveRealRefCnt(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.release(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:138)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:100)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpContent.release(DefaultHttpContent.java:92)
        at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(ReferenceCountUtil.java:88)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:340)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:358)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:647)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1526)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1287)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1324)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.channelRead(ProxyHandler.java:253)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper.channelRead(HttpProxyHandler.java:272)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2020-12-11 00:29:12.498 [reactor-http-nio-2] ERROR r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler - [id: 0xebbe5eff, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:55189] Error was received while reading the incoming data. The connection will be closed.
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
        at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.toLiveRealRefCnt(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.release(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:138)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:100)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpContent.release(DefaultHttpContent.java:92)
        at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(ReferenceCountUtil.java:88)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:340)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:358)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:647)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1526)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1287)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1324)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.channelRead(ProxyHandler.java:253)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper.channelRead(HttpProxyHandler.java:272)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this error was reported and resolved by spring-framework team. check https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1374

Or

You can add `codec` property in your property file.

```
spring
  codec:
    max-in-memory-size: 10MB
```

Comment: I think this works on the server-side, but my error occurs on the client side , perhaps this is a better approach?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59392022/618563

Comment: Yeah, this does not seem to work with WebClient

Answer (score 0):

this error happens when an object is not serialized. ensure the object and sub-objects that you store in the Redis cache are serialize.