# WebTestClient giving the error: org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144

Tags: java, spring-boot, webtestclient

I'm a beginner in spring boot. So I hope someone could help me to resolve the above error.

I'm getting the `DataBufferLimitException` while trying to test my application with `WebTestClient`. I have also set the `codec:max-in-memory-size: 10MB` in the application.yml file.

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-parent:3.1.4`

This is my test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
public class CustomerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
    private static final String CUSTOMER_URI = "api/v1/customers";

    @Test
    void canUploadAndDownloadProfilePictures() throws IOException {
        // create registration request
        Faker faker = new Faker();
        Name fakerName = faker.name();

        String name = fakerName.fullName();
        String email = fakerName.lastName() + "-" + UUID.randomUUID() + "@skynet.com";
        int age = RANDOM.nextInt(1, 100);

        Gender gender = age % 2 == 0 ? Gender.Male : Gender.Female;

        CustomerRegistrationRequest request = new CustomerRegistrationRequest(
                name, email, "password", age, gender
        );

        // send a post request
        String jwtToken = webTestClient.post()
                .uri(CUSTOMER_URI)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(Mono.just(request), CustomerRegistrationRequest.class)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk()
                .returnResult(Void.class)
                .getResponseHeaders()
                .get(AUTHORIZATION)
                .get(0);

        // get all customers
        List<CustomerDTO> allCustomers = webTestClient.get()
                .uri(CUSTOMER_URI)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header(AUTHORIZATION, String.format("Bearer %s", jwtToken))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk()
                .expectBodyList(new ParameterizedTypeReference<CustomerDTO>() {
                })
                .returnResult()
                .getResponseBody();

        CustomerDTO customerDTO = allCustomers.stream()
                .filter(customer -> customer.email().equals(email))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow();

        assertThat(customerDTO.profileImageId()).isNullOrEmpty();

        Resource image = new ClassPathResource(
                "%s.jpg".formatted(gender.name().toLowerCase())
        );

        MultipartBodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        bodyBuilder.part("file", image);

        // When

        // send a post request
        webTestClient.post()
                .uri(CUSTOMER_URI + "/{customerId}/profile-image", customerDTO.id())
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(bodyBuilder.build()))
                .header(AUTHORIZATION, String.format("Bearer %s", jwtToken))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk();

        // Then the profile image id should be populated

        // get customer by id
        String profileImageId = webTestClient.get()
                .uri(CUSTOMER_URI + "/{id}", customerDTO.id())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header(AUTHORIZATION, String.format("Bearer %s", jwtToken))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk()
                .expectBody(CustomerDTO.class)
                .returnResult()
                .getResponseBody()
                .profileImageId();

        assertThat(profileImageId).isNotBlank();

        // download image for customer
        byte[] downloadedImage = webTestClient.get()
                .uri(CUSTOMER_URI + "/{customerId}/profile-image", customerDTO.id())
                .accept(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk()
                .expectBody(byte[].class)
                .returnResult()
                .getResponseBody();

        byte[] actual = Files.toByteArray(image.getFile());

        assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(downloadedImage);

    }
}
```

This is the whole exception:

```
org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144

    at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.raiseLimitException(LimitedDataBufferList.java:99)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET http://localhost:60589/api/v1/customers/118/profile-image [DefaultClientResponse]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.raiseLimitException(LimitedDataBufferList.java:99)
        at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.updateCount(LimitedDataBufferList.java:92)
        at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.add(LimitedDataBufferList.java:58)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onNext(MonoCollect.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:377)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:411)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:734)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:114)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:144)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1738)
        at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultResponseSpec.expectBody(DefaultWebTestClient.java:444)
        at com.skynet.journey.CustomerIntegrationTest.canUploadAndDownloadProfilePictures(CustomerIntegrationTest.java:395)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
        at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

2024-01-27T14:35:03.386+05:30  INFO 1100 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-01-27T14:35:03.389+05:30  INFO 1100 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-01-27T14:35:03.397+05:30  INFO 1100 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: I wonder if this SO might help you, the OP has a similar Stack Trace:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326351/configure-spring-codec-max-in-memory-size-when-using-reactiveelasticsearchclient